# Is it practical to include an adaptive or optimizing memory strategy into a library?

Tags: buffer

I have a library that does I/O.  There are a couple of external knobs for tuning the sizes of the memory buffers used internally. When I ran some tests I found that the sizes of the buffers can affect performance significantly.

But the optimum size seems to depend on a bunch of things - the available memory on the PC, the the size of the files being processed (varies from very small to huge), the number of files, the speed of the output stream relative to the input stream, and I'm not sure what else.

Does it make sense to build an adaptive memory strategy into the library?  or is it better to just punt on that, and let the users of the library figure out what to use?

Has anyone done something like this - and how hard is it?  Did it work?

Given different buffer sizes, I suppose the library could track the time it takes for various operations, and then it could make some decisions about which size was optimal.  I could imagine having the library rotate through various buffer sizes in the initial I/O rounds... and then it eventually would do the calculations and adjust the buffer size in future rounds depending on the outcomes. But then, how often to re-check?  How often to adjust?

Comment: buffers are for old people.  Use memory maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adaptive approach is sometimes referred to as "autonomic", using the analogy of a Human's autonomic nervous system: you don't conciously control your heart rate and respiration, your autonomic nervous system does that.

You can read about some of this [here](http://www.research.ibm.com/autonomic/), and [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/tivoli/autonomic/) (apologies for the plugs, but I wanted to show that the concept is being taken seriously, and is manifesting in real products.)

My experience of using products that try to do this is that they do acually work, but can make me unhappy: that's because there is a tendency for them to take a "Father knows best" approach. You make some (you believe) small change to your app, or the environment and something unexecpected happens. You don't know why, and you don't know if it's good. So my rule for autonomy is:

> Tell me what you are doing and **why**

Now sometimes the underlying math is quite complex - consider that some autonomic systems are trending and hence making predictive changes (number of requests of this type growing, let's provision more of resource X) so the mathematical models are non-trivial. Hence simple explanations are not always available. However some level of feedback to the watching humans can be reassuring.